# Getting too many connection for role when using DataSource

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, datasource, jdbctemplate

I have a Rest service and when it gets it has to do some insertion and updation to almost 25 database. So when I tried like the below code, it was working in my localhost but when I deploy to my staging server I was getting **FATAL: too many connections for role "user123"**

```
List<String> databaseUrls = null;
databaseUrls.forEach( databaseUrl -> {
    DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
            .url(databaseUrl)
            .username("user123")
            .password("some-password")
            .build();
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    jdbcTemplate.update("Some...Update...Query");
});
```

As per my understanding **DataSource** need not to be closed because it is never opened.

Note:

> A **DataSource** implementation need not be closed, because it is never
>   **“opened”**. A **DataSource** is not a resource, is not connected to the
>   database, so it is not holding networking connections nor resources on
>   the database server. A DataSource is simply information needed when
>   making a connection to the database, with the database server's
>   network name or address, the user name, user password, and various
>   options you want specified when a connection is eventually made.

Can someone tell why I am getting this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in DataSourceBuilder, it actually creates of the connection pools which spawns some number of connections and keeps them running:

```
private static final String[] DATA_SOURCE_TYPE_NAMES = new String[] {
            "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource",
            "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource",
            "org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" };
```

Javadoc says:

```
/**
 * Convenience class for building a {@link DataSource} with common implementations and
 * properties. If Tomcat, HikariCP or Commons DBCP are on the classpath one of them will
 * be selected (in that order with Tomcat first). In the interest of a uniform interface,
 * and so that there can be a fallback to an embedded database if one can be detected on
 * the classpath, only a small set of common configuration properties are supported. To
 * inject additional properties into the result you can downcast it, or use
 * <code>@ConfigurationProperties</code>.
 */
```

Try to use e.g. [SingleConnectionDataSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/SingleConnectionDataSource.html), then your problem will gone:

```
List<String> databaseUrls = null;
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
databaseUrls.forEach( databaseUrl -> {
    SingleConnectionDataSource dataSource;
    try {
        dataSource = new SingleConnectionDataSource(
                databaseUrl, "user123", "some-password", true /*suppressClose*/);
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.update("Some...Update...Query");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Failed to run queries for {}", databaseUrl, e);
    } finally {
        // release resources
        if (dataSource != null) {
            dataSource.destroy();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But Connection Pooling is really good right so that pool will take care of the connection instead of creating a new one everytime

Comment: Yeah, but it spawns some initial number of connections and keeps them running. Try to reduce number of connection or use  SingleConnectionDataSource. In your case one connection is enough.

Comment: But this is a rest service which will be called every 30 min, so do you think pooling wont be a better solution.

Comment: It's fine for your case as you enough one connection per database to perform all your queries. You don't need to spawn more than one.

Comment: And yeah, you need to be sure that you close your connections.

Comment: do that means I need to close this connection everytime.....I saw one function in `SingleConnectionDataSource` called `setSuppressClose`, what does that do if I set it to true

Comment: Right, setSuppressClose instruct to use connection proxy which will prevent it from closing while using. But anyway, after you've done, you have to call destroy to close the actual connection and release resources.

Answer (score 1):

First thing it is very bad architecture decision to have single application managing 50 database. Anyway instead of creating DataSource in for loop, you should make use of Factory Design pattern to create DataSource for each DB. You should add some connection pooling mechanism to your system . HijariCP and TomcatPool are most widely used. Analyse logs of failure thread for any further issues.

Comment: See my comment just below about DataSourceBuilder. The problem that it has pool and don't release resources.